# Display the result of a calculation in Google Sheet to the user after he sent a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps, google-forms

I created a Google Form that send its results to a Google Sheet for further calculations. Therefore, I'd like to display the results of those calculations to the user once he has sent the Google Form (either instantly or via email).

How can I achieve this ? Should I use a module ? Or a Google Apps Script ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: It looks that you are asking for a tool/resource recommendation but that is off-topic on this site. Please checkout [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, check out two addons for Google sheets, autoCract and Docotpus. We use them all the time to get and send student's results. They are very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that, You are collecting data from multiple user into the spread sheet collect their email Id's as well along with other data,

**How to get email Id column in spreadsheet?**

Go inside google form edit mode -> see the settings icon from the right corner of the page > click on that -> check the **Collect email addresses** checkbox -> Save.

Now, you will have **Email Address** column in the spreadsheet.
Lets suppose you are receiving the marks of 3 subject, calculate the sum of those these 3 values, same for each users records(row) in loop or use **VLOOKUP/ formula** to calculate sum, get email address from the same row of the respective user and send mail to that user using **MailApp**  api and add sum inside email body with some text formatting.